# How to guard route if HTTP GET request returns no data?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-guards

Below is a table in my Angular app. It is populated with data from `employees.json`:

```
<tbody>
    <tr *ngFor="let employee of employees">
        <td (click)="viewEmployeeProfile(1, employee.id)">{{employee.fullName}}
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

When the user clicks on a name, the `employeeId` is passed to this method:

```
viewEmployeeProfile(roleId: number, employeeId: number) {
    this._router.navigate(['/profile', roleId, employeeId]);
}
```

Here is the route in my `AppRouting` module:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'profile/:role/:id',
    component: ProfileComponent,
    // canActivate: [RequireEmployeeProfileGuardGuard]
  },
  { 
    path: 'page-not-found', 
    component: PageNotFoundComponent 
  },
  { 
    path: '**', 
    component: PageNotFoundComponent
  }
];
```

Example path: `http://localhost:4200/profile/1/4`

When the user routes to the`Profile` component, this code is called:

profile.component.ts:

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.route.paramMap.subscribe(params => {
    const roleId = +params.get('role');
    const empId = +params.get('id');
    this.getEmployee(empId);
    });
```

}

```
getEmployee(id: number) {
    this.employeeService.getEmployee(id).subscribe(
      (employee: IEmployee) => this.displayEmployee(employee),
      (err: any) => console.log(err)
    );
}

displayEmployee(employee: IEmployee) {
    this.employee.fullName = employee.fullName;
}
```

profile.component.html:

```
<tr>
    <td><b>Full Name</b></td>
    <td>{{employee.fullName}}</td>
</tr>
```

And here is my `employee.service`:

```
baseUrl = 'http://localhost:3000/employees';

getEmployee(id: number): Observable<IEmployee> {
    return this.httpClient.get<IEmployee>(`${this.baseUrl}/${id}`)
        .pipe(catchError(this.handleError));
    }
```

This code is working fine, & displays data as expected.

Currently, if I navigate to a route such as `http://localhost:4200/profile/1/123456789`, where that `employeeId` does not exist, the `Profile`component is displayed with no data.

Instead of this, I would want the user to be brought back to the `PageNotFound` component.

Here are my current routes:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: 'profile/:role/:id', component: ProfileComponent },
  { path: '**', component: PageNotFoundComponent }
];
```

Can someone please tell me what changes I need to make to implement this?

Comment: Try using resolvers to fetch data instead of fetching them inside component. And within the resolver, redirect to a particular route if no data is returned by api.

Comment: In your `getEmployee` method after fetch check if emplyee is there if so then use `displayEmployee` else redirect to page not found

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a perfect opportunity for the [CanActivate](https://angular.io/api/router/CanActivate) guard.

Since Angular 7.1.0, route guards may now return a [URLTree](https://angular.io/api/router/UrlTree) which gives us some really cool flexibility in our guards. [Here](https://blog.angularindepth.com/new-in-angular-v7-1-updates-to-the-router-fd67d526ad05) is a nice article that goes over the changes and what they mean / how they can be used.

I would suggest you create your guard. Something like the following:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { CanActivate, Router, UrlTree, ActivatedRouteSnapshot } from '@angular/router';
import { Observable, of } from 'rxjs';
import { map, catchError } from 'rxjs/operators';
// import your employee service here

@Injectable()
export class RequireEmployeeProfileGuard implements CanActivate {
  constructor(private router: Router, private employeeService: EmployeeService) {
  }

  canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot): Observable<boolean | UrlTree> {
    return this.employeeService.getEmployee(+route.paramMap.get('id')).pipe(
      catchError(() => of(false)),
      map(employee => !!employee || this.router.parseUrl('page-not-found'))
    );
  }
}
```

From here, just go to your Routing Module, import this guard and add it to your route like this:

```
{ 
  path: 'profile/:role/:id', 
  component: ProfileComponent,
  canActivate: [RequireEmployeeProfileGuard]
}
```

I would also probably define an explicitly named route for the error component too like:

```
{ 
  path: 'page-not-found', 
  component: PageNotFoundComponent 
}
```

So then `'absolute-redirect-url-here'` from the guard above would become `'page-not-found'`.

Also, since you would still want to have a 'catch-all' case for invalid URLs, you would probably want a route like:

```
{ 
  path: '**', 
  redirectTo: 'page-not-found'
}
```

So how does this work?

It might look complex but it's very simple at its core really. The magic is in the `canActivate()` method that we added to the guard:

We are requesting the employee profile from the `employeeService` and converting it to a boolean using the double-not operator (basically, checking "do we have a matching employee profile"). If this converts to a `false` then the `URLTree` is returned which will redirect the router to the specified, absolute route.

When any route is being resolved, Angular will run through all the guards attached to it in a pre-defined order. If **any** of the guards 'fail' then the route won't be loaded.

Answer (score 0):

You can modify your `getEmployee` method to do so something like

```
getEmployee(id: number) {
    this.employeeService.getEmployee(id).subscribe(
      (employee: IEmployee) => {
         if(employee){
          this.displayEmployee(employee)
        }else{
          //redirect to page not found here
       }
      },
      (err: any) => console.log(err)
    );
}
```

Comment: I would not personally recommend this. Why should the `getEmployee()` method deal with route redirecting? Doing so violates the [Single Responsibility Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle). This method should get an employee and do nothing else

Answer (score 0):

Add below routings to `AppRouting` module

```
{path: '404', component: NotFoundComponent},
{path: '**', redirectTo: '/404'}
```

The above route will catch incorrect routes at the root level and within any nested children as well.put this path as the last path in your routing module

call `gotoHeroes` method from the `getEmployee` method if records count is 0 or null

```
gotoHeroes() {
  this.router.navigate(['/404']);
}
```